# One particular DVD drive is not detected in one particular PC

Tags: windows-10, optical-drive

I have several PCs running Windows 10 and several optical drives. One of the drives is not detected on one of the PCs. The same drive works fine in other PCs, and other drives works fine on the "bad" PC. On the "bad" PC, the drive is detected by BIOS but not visible anywhere in Windows (not even in device manager).

What could cause this?

The drive is a farily standard HP/Hitachi-LG "GH40L" ripped from a random HP business desktop.
The troubling PC is custom-built with an Intel DH77DF motherboard. It has two hard drives in RAID1 configuration (Intel RST).

Other details:

- In the RST settings, the SATA port it is connected to is hidden. This might be normal.
- If I press F10 to select boot device on boot, it is not included (but it might be because there was no disk in the drive).
- Even in the bad PC, the drive ejects etc
- Working and non-working optical drives were connected to the same power and data cables

Things I've tried:

- Different power and data cables
- Flipping a lot of UEFI settings
- Deleting "LowerFilter" and "UpperFilter" from registry (they did not exist)
- Adding the "Device enumeration" registry keys
- Uninstalling everything that might be messing with SATA, such as Imgburn, Macrium Reflect,
- In device manager, uninstalling all devices related to RST, disks and optical drives, including "hidden devices"

Things I have yet to try:

- Firmware update of the drive

EDIT: Later on, the drive failed in another PC as well (one that it had previously ran on). All PCs very running Windows 10.

Comment: Maybe that Sata/Ide port is disabled in the bios?

Comment: Hello there. I do not see here if you have tested using another SATA port on the said computer. Are you sure the SATA port is enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: Hello! I have tried multiple other drives in the same SATA port and with the same cables, all working fine :(

Comment: Hmm, at this point I'd indeed try a firmware update. https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktops-Archive-Read-Only/Latest-firmware-for-HP-DVD-RAM-GH40L-ATA-Device-DVD-Burner/td-p/2317339 . The link to the firmware is in the second post.

Comment: If the firmware update doesn't help, sometimes two devices just don't work together. This means that both devices are a bit off the norm.

Comment: Have you tried a different SATA port?  Since you have RAID enabled, certain SATA ports might be limited to RAID array, if it's enabled

Comment: Well now I feel silly, the firmware update did indeed fix the issue. Feel free to make it a proper answer!